How can I change the password for VeraCrypt container in Windows XP?
I created VeraCrypt container and added files to it. It was made in Windows 10. I used latest version of the software.
Can I change password for the container in Windows XP? VeraCrypt 1.25.9 or older will be installed.

It is likely that VeraCrypt v. 1.25.9, the last version for XP, cannot even open a VeraCrypt container made with a later version. The latest versions intentionally have removed compatibility with some older formats, both reading and writing.
Since VeraCrypt is all about security, and Windows XP itself is considered insecure, why not move to a currently-supported operating system on which current versions of VeraCrypt run?
For example, current versions of VeraCrypt run on "Linux x86, x86-64". Whether that is a 32-bit or 64-bit XP PC, there are numerous Linux distros that could be installed, or in many cases, booted and run from USB. If you need a 32-bit OS for an ancient machine, there are many options. Installing VeraCrypt on Ubuntu or other Debian derivative is simple.

Thank you for answer.  It helped greatly.
